# Getting issue regarding to get selector in the selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipse

AS per the screen shot there are more then two botton of the add to cart and all button class name are same . so how can i identify the each and every one by the on click event->ajax id [image]

Comment: Can you add the HTML code as well so we can help you to select the add to cart button based on the your item

Comment: how to add the HTML code? i have try this 
 WebElement addtocart=s1.getDriver().findElement(By.className("product-box-add-to-cart-button"));
  addtocart.click();

Comment: If your requirement to get all those 2 button then use index in your xpath

Comment: ok i have to check for that

Comment: Actually there are compound classes in your tag so `className` wont work. use this `//input[@class='button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button']` and let me know

Comment: Comments should not be used to answer to questions.

Comment: @NarendraR i have try but it not working

Answer (score 1):

Without the full DOM structure, I would guess by the UI:

Probably there is a root where the two button elements derive uniquely.

```
Some common node
└── ├── Image Node
                  ├── Image tag
                  └── Button tag
    ├── QR Code Node
                  ├── QR Code tag
                  └── Button tag
```

So, if you want to reach the image input, your css selector is *.css_class_of_the_image_node input*. If you want to reach the image input, your css selector is *.css_class_of_the_QR_code_node input*.

Comment: To be fully complete, the css selectors would be `.css_class_of_the_image_node input .product-box-add-to-cart-button` or `.css_class_of_the_QR_code_node input .product-box-add-to-cart-button`

Comment: I think input.product-box-add-to-cart-button is the case, since the product-box-add-to-cart-button is a class of the input elements. Using as you suggested would search for a element which has the named class INSIDE the input element - thus would find nothing because there is nothing inside input elements.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the 'input' part, also when copy pasting. Your original solution was correct and also agree with your last comment.